# Forwarding IP Camera using Nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am running an nginx container [jlesage/nginx-proxy-manager](https://hub.docker.com/r/jlesage/nginx-proxy-manager) on a QNAP NAS. I am trying to create a reverse proxy so that requests on my local network going to `http://nginx:12345/` will forward to an Amcrest IP Camera that uses authentication:

```
http://username:password@AmcrestCam/cgi-bin/mjpg/video.cgi?channel=1&subtype=1
```

The end goal is that the `http://nginx:12345` renders without authentication.

In proxy manager, I try these settings but cannot save:

[Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vi1G9.png)
[Custom Locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTqOu.png)